# Помогите создать резиновое меню без display: table-cell; Есть два варианта

Tags: css

Какой из этих вариантов будет наиболее корректныйм?

```css
ul{
 border:1px black solid;
}
li{
 display:inline-block;
 width:16%;
}
a{
 display:inline-block;
 padding:12px 0;
 background:red;
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="#">123</a></li>
<li><a href="#">123</a></li>
</ul>
```

```css
ul{
 border:1px black solid;
}
li{
 display:inline;
}
a{
 display:inline-block;
 padding:12px 0;
 background:red;
 width:16%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="#">123</a></li>
<li><a href="#">123</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `width` не в процентах а в pixel, http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/aBBQxO?editors=1100

Answer (score 1):

Для лучшего эффекта резины соверую вам использовать **flexbox**, так как он действительно резиновый, и сейчас поддерживается многими браузерами.

Answer (score 0):

И так, и так приемлемо, это дело вкуса, какой вариант больше нравится

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/122717)

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko Почему не является ответом на вопрос? Человек спрашивает, какой вариант более корректный, я отвечаю, что разница непринципиальна.

Comment: потому что это больше похоже на комментарий, нежели на полноценный ответ!